# Book recommend for Tikhonov regularization

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I need regularization in studying inverse partial differential problems. Therefore i want to learn regularization techniques especially Tikhonov regularization. Can you recommend any book which contains descriptive examples.

Answer (score 1):

Colton and Kress' [Inverse Acoustic and Electromagnetic Scattering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461449413) has a good treatment, along with generalizations like the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm and many practical algorithms for solving inverse problems where regularization must be applied.